# Ajax post requests in ServiceWorkers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, service-worker

Is it possible to make ajax post request in ServiceWorkers execution?

I have a Service Worker registered that just "listen" for a push notification.

I need to call a PHP function (in order to read some data from my database) during the execution of the Service Worker (when receiving the push notification), but I'm not able to do it. When I call the ajax post it goes to "error" section and the error is "No Transport" (I tried to add the "jQuery.support.cors = true;" like suggested in other thread, but this not fixed the issue).

Here below the serviceworker code.

Is it impossible to do what I'm trying to do, or I'm doing something wrong?

```
    var document = self.document = {parentNode: null, nodeType: 9, toString: function() {return "FakeDocument"}};
var window = self.window = self;
var fakeElement = Object.create(document);
fakeElement.nodeType = 1;
fakeElement.toString=function() {return "FakeElement"};
fakeElement.parentNode = fakeElement.firstChild = fakeElement.lastChild = fakeElement;
fakeElement.ownerDocument = document;

document.head = document.body = fakeElement;
document.ownerDocument = document.documentElement = document;
document.getElementById = document.createElement = function() {return fakeElement;};
document.createDocumentFragment = function() {return this;};
document.getElementsByTagName = document.getElementsByClassName = function() {return [fakeElement];};
document.getAttribute = document.setAttribute = document.removeChild = 
document.addEventListener = document.removeEventListener = 
function() {return null;};
document.cloneNode = document.appendChild = function() {return this;};
document.appendChild = function(child) {return child;};

importScripts('js/jquery.js');  



self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    var endpoint = "";

    if (event.data) {
        endpoint = event.data.text();
    }

    var data = {
        query: "SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE ENDPOINT  = '" + endpoint + "'"
    };

    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        method: "POST",
        url: 'ExecuteQueryJquery.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (obj, textstatus) {
            var o = obj;
        },
        error: function (obj, textstatus) {
            var o = obj;
        }
    });

});
```